# How do you open the browser overlay in steamworks to a given address?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

I've searched google dozens of ways, and yet I can't seem to find out how to perform the simple (?) action of *opening the browser overlay in steam to go to a given address.*

In my case, when a user does something, it's meant to trigger a browser opening to a given address.

What should I be looking into to get started on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SteamFriends.ActivateGameOverlayToWebPage("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
```